# OnChange attribute on custom DropDownList not being rendered

Tags: asp.net, attributes, drop-down-menu, custom-controls

I have a custom usercontrol, which is basically a dropdownlist, prepopulated with values from the database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selResponseTimes" runat="server" SkinID="filterSkin">                
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Response_Times_Drop_Down : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable objDataTable = DAL.ExecuteDataTable("sp_cl_Response_Times_Get", null);
            selResponseTimes.DataSource = objDataTable;
            selResponseTimes.DataTextField = "TM_Code";
            selResponseTimes.DataValueField = "TM_Code";
            selResponseTimes.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return selResponseTimes.SelectedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            selResponseTimes.SelectedValue = value;
        }
    }

}
```

The control is added to my page as follows, and works fine:

```
<asp:ResponseTimesDropDown runat="server" ID="selResponse" />
```

I'm adding client side events as attributes to standard controls on `Page_Load` using the following:

```
txtCallRelatedCall.Attributes.Add("onblur", "CheckRelatedCall()");
```

However, when I attempt to do this with my custom control they are not being added.

```
selResponse.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CalculateResponseTime()");
```

However if I debug the code, the attributes are being added to the collection, it appears that they are just not being output to the page. Why is this?

Comment: can you show us the javacript and the html part ? Also try to set "CheckRelatedCall();return false;" and "CalculateResponseTime();return false;" to see if works.

Comment: This is irrelevant, I'm never getting to call the javascript, because I'm not able to successfully add the onchange attribute to my control.

Comment: My assumption is that, because i am able to add attributes to standard controls on the `Page_Load` event, and not my custom control, it is because the control has already been rendered so I need to add the attribute at an earlier stage?

Comment: You need to add the `onchange` event to the `DropDownList` inside your control.

Comment: Thanks, I have ended up doing this but I consider it a hack really, as I have instances of this control where I do not which to fire the client side event, so have had to include an empty function on these pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what stage of the page lifecycle are you adding the attributes?

Try adding them in on `Page_Init`

```
Protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selResponse.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CalculateResponseTime()");
}
```

**EDIT (See Comments):**

```
Public void CalculateResponseEnabled()
{
        selResponseTimes.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CalculateResponseTime()");
}
```

Then in the from you can call CalculateResponseEnabled by doing.

```
selResponse.CalculateResponseEnabled();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding them in Page_Load, I also tried them in Page_PreRender to no avail. Just tried Page_Init there with no success.

Comment: Is there any reason you add it from the form and not inside the control? If you add it inside the control to selResponseTimes it should work.

Comment: My logic was that this is a reusable control. I would not necessarily want to have a client-side onchange event with every use of the control, just on this particular page.

Comment: Fair point. Ive updated the answer to not use a property and simply call a method to add it. let me know how it goes

Comment: Cool glad I could help. Maybe best to delete some of the comments above that aren't used in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I added my code to the OnPreRender event of the particular control I was using, and it started working.